# Ways of withdrawing tokens from an array of addresses

Tags: solidity, gas, arrays, optimization

I want to withdraw tokens from every address registered in a contract.

One way to do this is to iterate over an array of addresses 0 to array.length and withdraw from every single element. From what I've seen this is not scalable.

Are there any scalable ways to withdraw/transfer tokens from a list of addresses?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this is not really scalable and can also use a lot of Gas for all the transactions.

I do not really know what your code looks like, but I suggest looking for an alternative solution to do this.

**A better method could be:**
Let all addresses deposit into the same pool, but use a mapping to track the amount that a certain address has in the pool. This way, if you want to withdraw all funds (Each address') its one transaction. And a user can withdraw their amount individually as well.

This is also scalable and dynamic. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Mapping is useful when tracking balances, users are withdrawing individually it is ok. Though I am trying to distribute tokens to all depositors when distribute() function is called. I don't think this is possible using a mapping.

Comment: It is definitely possible, you will have a dynamic mapping array of all depositors. You can then use your method and loop through it to send to everyone. Although this will cost a lot